# sending string value from classes extending BaseAdapter to Overlay

Tags: android

i am writing a code where i get a string value in a class that extends BaseAdapter. I want this value to be used in another class that extends an Overlay.  If my class extends an Activity i can use intent,putstring() and getString, but is to be used for these above specified classes..Can anyone tell me how can i do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either make your variable global or make a singleton FileHelper class that contains values you want to pass between classes.

MyClass:

```
public String myString = "Hello";
```

and if you want to use it in 
OtherClass:

```
String myString = MyClass.myString;
```

If your the FileHelper use this:

```
public class FileHelper {

    private static FileHelper instance;
    private String myString;

    private FileHelper() {
    }

    public static FileHelper getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new FileHelper();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void setMyString(String s){
        myString = s;
    }

    public String getMyString(){
        return myString();
    }
}
```

You can use the FileHelper with this:

```
private static FileHelper fileHelper = FileHelper.getInstance();
fileHelper.setString("hello");
String myString = fileHelper.getMyString();
```